# Notepad++ - Copy text between sign

Tags: multiple-monitors, notepad++, regex

I need please your help :
I have this text like this :

```
</span>Seller: sunnybeauty04 (1,702) 98.6%<span
</span>Seller: 168tradeworld-au (2,357) 99.1%<span
</span>Seller: rna-e-mart (4) 100%<span
</span>Seller: ouyou2010 (1,186,025) 97%<span
</span>Seller: hzch-56 (52) 96.4%<span
</span>Seller: hlx_tech (16,592) 98%<span
```

And I need the at the end to get this text :

```
sunnybeauty04 
168tradeworld-au
rna-e-mart
ouyou2010 
hzch-56
hlx_tech
```

Many thanks in advance to all the helpers

Comment: Is it a typo or do you want to extract part of text between `</span>` && `<span`?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming there is a typo in your question and all lines are like:

```
<span>Seller: sunnybeauty04 (1,702) 98.6%</span>
```

---

This does the job.

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `<span>Seller: (\S+).+$`
- Replace with: `$1`
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- **UNCHECK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
<span>Seller:       # literally
(\S+)               # group 1, 1 or more non space characters
.+                  # 1 or more any character but newline
$                   # end of line
```

**Replacement:**

```
$1      # content of group 1 (i.e. the mac address)
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]